# Download Audio/Video file using iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Currently my iframe is showing the Video/Audio instead of downloading it.

Zip files work fine though.

Thats the code:

```
    <iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="https://example.com/downloads/1.mp3"></iframe>
```

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it download why are you using a iframe? you can simply do this

```
<a href="https://example.com/downloads/1.mp3" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>
```

Comment: You would need to click the link using this method - by using iframe users wont need to click a link